# Find whether an array has a substring corresponding to another element in a new array JS

Tags: javascript

I get the value of "name" from a promise and I store it in an array as it MAY contain multiple names.

```
var name = ["Arun_Manohar"];
var combinations = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "har", "lmn"];
```

Lets say I have an activities object.

```
var activities = {
    driving: false,
    jogging: false,
    drinking: false
}
```

How do I go about writing a check to update the activities object in this case.
NOTE: No two elements in combinations array will be a substring of names array. Just one.

Case: Since name contains a substring of one of the elements of combinations, I need to update the activities object. If the name contains a substring like "abc", I will update the object with different values.

Use of lodash would be great.

Tried something and wasnt able to update the object.

```
if(name.indexOf(_.filter(combinations, function(e) { return.indexOf("har") !== -1})) !== -1) {
    activities.driving= true;
    activities.jogging= true;
}
```

If the name contains "abcpoc", since the substring is present in combinations array, I update the object with a different set of values.

Comment: I don't understand, what does the activities object have to do with the two arrays?

Comment: Its nothing related to do with it. I just want to know how it might work.

Comment: You say you want to update the activities object. Update it with what?

Comment: Loop through the two arrays, using `indexOf()` to test if the substring is found. If it is, update `activities`.

Comment: @Barmar If its a substring that matches with "Arun_manohar" like "har", then I update the value of driving and jogging to be true

Comment: If you're using underscore.js or lodash, add that to your tags.

Comment: Yeah thats there in my code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using lodash, you can use `_.intersectionWith`, using a comparator function that uses `indexOf()`.

```
matched_combos = _.intersectionWith(combinations, names, (combo, name) => name.indexOf(combo) != -1);
```

Then you can loop through `matched_combos` to add appropriate things to `activities`:

```
matched_combos.forEach(str => {
    switch(str) {
        "har":
            activities.driving = true;
            activities.jogging = true;
            break;
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = ["Arun_Manohar"];
var combos = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "har", "lmn"];
var activities = {};

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < combos.length; j++) {
      if (names[i].indexOf(combos[j]) >= 0) {
          activities.driving = true; //or whatever you need here;
      }
   }
}
```

Yo can also extend this code with additional checks and continue/break statements to avoid additional unnecessary loops if corresponding substring was already found.

Comment: Hey Artem, is there a way I can give the value of an element in the combinations array for the check? Like since "har" is present I update the object. If the names array is ["abcpoc"], and since "abc" is present, I want to update the object with a different set of values.

Comment: which element do you mean?

Comment: Element in the sense an item in the array.

Comment: @a2441918 If you're looking for a specific string like `"har"`, why do you need the `combinations` array?

Comment: Actually `names[i]` is and element from names array and `combos[j]` is an element from combos array. You can do any check you need with those values.

Comment: Its not specifically "har". The combinations array is fixed. No elements inside it will change. The elements inside name array changes. If there is a substring match with "abc" from combinations array, I update the object with differnent values. If there is a match with "har", I update it with different values.

Comment: If combinations are never changed and every specific combination means different things you should probably use `switch/case` or a set of `if` blocks. Check @Barmar answer for that and try use it or combine with my.

Comment: Yeah Artem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is ES5 solution with `indexOf`:

```js
var names = ["Arun_Manohar"];
var combinations = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "har", "lmn"];
var activities = {
    driving: false,
    jogging: false,
    drinking: false
}


for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < combinations.length; j++) {
     if(names[i].indexOf(combinations[j]) >= 0) {
       activities.name = names[i]
     }
  }
}

console.log(activities);
```

And here is ES6 solution with `includes`:

```js
var names = ["Arun_Manohar"];
var combinations = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "har", "lmn"];
var activities = {
    driving: false,
    jogging: false,
    drinking: false
}


for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < combinations.length; j++) {
     if(names[i].includes(combinations[j])) {
       activities.name = names[i]
     }
  }
}

console.log(activities);
```

And here is more elegant ES6 solution with `includes`, `forEach` iterating method and arrow functions:

```js
var names = ["Arun_Manohar"];
var combinations = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "har", "lmn"];
var activities = {
    driving: false,
    jogging: false,
    drinking: false
}


names.forEach(item1 => {
  combinations.forEach(item2 => {
    if(item1.includes(item2)) {
      activities.name = item1;
    }
  });
});

console.log(activities);
```